# Facebook Group API - No Preview

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

Good afternoon,

Any knows why when I make a group post through the API with for example the following link:
- https://www.motocasiao.pt/advert/8F70CC3EF/ktm-1190-adventure

No preview is generated, only the url is shown..

Output: https://prnt.sc/q05517

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/

> When content is shared for the first time, the Facebook crawler will scrape and cache the metadata from the URL shared. The crawler has to see an image at least once before it can be rendered. This means that the first person who shares a piece of content won't see a rendered image.
>
> There are three ways to avoid this and have images render on the first Like or Share action:
>
> 1. Pre-cache the image with the Sharing Debugger: Run the URL through the URL debugger to pre-fetch metadata for the page. This can also be used to update the image for a piece of content.
> 2. Pre-cache the image using Graph API: Perform a force-scrape of the URL programmatically using the Graph API to pre-fetch metadata for the page . This can also be used to update the image for a piece of content.
> 3. Use og:image:width and og:image:height Open Graph tags: Using these tags will specify the image dimensions to the crawler so that it can render the image immediately without having to asynchronously download and process it.

Comment: First of all let me thank you for the reply @ceejayoz !